# Вопрос по ООП java

Tags: java, классы

Есть основной класс Main и класс Person в классе Person есть метод draw(), что-бы исползовать этот метод в классе Main надо создать объект 
Person maks = new Person() ;
И с помощью него исползовать метод maks.draw(),
Как на прямую исползовать метод draw без создания объекта?

Comment: Сделать метод статическим. Статические методы относятся к типу, а не к экземпляру.

Comment: Зачем тогда вам ООП, если вы хотите чтобы все оставалось в процедурном стиле?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того есть ли привязанность состояния объекта и его поведения, то есть, грубо говоря, используете ли вы ключевое слово `this` внутри метода `draw()`? Если нет, тогда без проблем ставьте `static` и это даже будет более вернее и доступиться до метода можно будет через имя класса: `Person.draw();`